# How to get a 5/5/5 ruler for the achievement named Truly Divine Ruler?

Tags: achievements, europa-universalis-iv

There is an achievement named *Truly Divine Ruler*.

The description is : *Get a 5/5/5 Ruler*.

Considering you can't choose directly your next ruler, **is there a way to get this achievement excluding luck ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is as a republic, just keep reelecting the same ruler until his stats are 5/5/5. You can shop around republics at the start and see if one of the rulers is already close so you might need only a single election (Venice is one such choice as of writing this).

Comment: Venice is the easiest candidate - they start with 4-4-4. You need only one reelection